# Django - table renders a blank row from query set

Tags: python, html, css, django, sass

I have a model named Season and a model named Game:

```
# Season
    class Season(models.Model):
    teams = models.ManyToManyField('Team', related_name='season_teams', blank=True)
    current = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(2018),
            MaxValueValidator(datetime.datetime.now().year)],
        help_text="Use the following format: <YYYY>", null=True, blank=True)
    session = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['year', 'session']

    def __str__(self):
        session = self.session
        year = str(self.year)
        season = session + " " + year
        return season

# Game
    class Game(models.Model):
    field_choices = FIELD_CHOICES
    team_choices = TEAM_CHOICES
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, choices=team_choices)
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, choices=team_choices)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=field_choices, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False, blank=True, default='')
    tbd = 'TBD'
    win = 'W'
    draw = 'D'
    loss = 'L'
    result_choices = (
                      (tbd, 'TBD'),
                      (win, 'W'),
                      (draw, 'D'),
                      (loss, 'L'),
                      )
    result = models.CharField(
                            max_length=3,
                            choices=result_choices,
                            default=tbd,
                            )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['home_team', 'away_team', 'field','score', 'result']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

I have a view Season which queries both models successfully:

```
# Season
    class Season(generic.ListView):
    model = SeasonModel
    template_name = 'team/season.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs1 = SeasonModel.objects.filter(current=True)
        qs2 = GameModel.objects.all().order_by('date')
        queryset1 = sorted(chain(qs1))
        queryset2 = sorted(chain(qs2),key=attrgetter('home_team'))
        result = queryset1 + queryset2
        return result
```

And then a template which is supposed to render the team's schedule, but it renders it with an extra blank row, as if I created a Game instance with blank attributes. This is my template:

```
<div id="schedule_header">
    <h5 id="datetime">Today's date is {% now "DATE_FORMAT" %}</h5>
    {% for season in object_list %}
    {% if season.current %}
    <a href=""><h5 id="session">{{ season.year }} {{ season.session }} session</h5></a>
    <a href=""><h5 id="season_history">Past Seasons</h5></a>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

<table class="table" id="e_schedule">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="thead"><h2>Week</h2></th>
      <th id="thead"><h2>Matchup</h2></th>
      <th id="thead"><h2>Field</h2></th>
      <th id="thead"><h2>Date/time</h2></th>
      <th id="thead"><h2>Score</h2></th>
      <th id="thead"><h2>Result</h2></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  {% for game in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <th id="counter"><p>{{ forloop.counter }}</p></th>
    <th id="matchup"><p>{{ game.home_team }} vs. {{ game.away_team }}</p></th>
    <th id="field"><p>{{ game.get_field_display }}</p></th>
    <th id="date"><p>{{ game.date.date }} at {{ game.date.time }}</p></th>
    <th id="score"><p>{{ game.score }}</p></th>
    <th id="result"><p>{{ game.result }}</p></th>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

So my question is how can I do this without rendering an extra blank row in the table? I'm guessing it has something to do with the chain itertool I use in the view because when I just do a simple query for Game this does not happen.

Comment: why do you combine two different queryset into a single one? let the queryset only for SeasonModel, and send the other queryset through context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because you combine two differents queryset.
Variables can be sent through context:

```
class Season(generic.ListView):
    model = SeasonModel
    template_name = 'team/season.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SeasonModel.objects.filter(current=True)

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(Season,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['games_list'] = GameModel.objects.all().order_by('date')
        return context
```

in yout html, you have two different variables

```
{% for season in object_list %}
    <a href=""><h5 id="session">{{ season.year }} {{ season.session }} session</h5></a>
    '''
{% endfor %}
```

for the game you have `games_list`

```
{% for game in games_list %}
<tr>
   '''
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow, worked like a charm. I was stuck on that one all day. I upvoted you, but not sure if it counts as I'm a new guy. Thanks for your help and being quick to reply.